# Can I use flatpack softwares in two distros?

Tags: software-installation

I installed flatpack softwares in my /home.
I want to use one /home in two distributions.
Can I run Flatpack softwares in a new distribution؟

Comment: It will mean the two distributions will be running the same version of the program, which will avoid the pitfalls/problems that can occur if the two distributions are using different versions of the same programs (*and data loss that can occur in that case*), so non *deb*/*rpm* can have its benefits where two systems share datafiles.... alas it's program specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on software that the Linux distributions use to install flatpak applications. In Ubuntu and Debian you need to install the flatpak package (`sudo apt install flatpak`) in order to install flatpak applications.

If you installed the flatpak applications in your `/home` directory it depends on how you installed them, so try using them in the new Linux distribution and see what happens. If there is a software like flatpak in Ubuntu that can be installed in the other Linux distribution then reinstalling it that way will work.

Comment: I want to share my /home/usr folder in which Flatpack software is installed between two distros. Can I easily run flatpack software in the new distribution after installing the new distro?

Comment: I added my reply to my answer.